# IIIF: Get list of ids for all pages in book given one page in book

Tags: iiif

I'm trying to download all page images from a book, and those images are hosted on a IIIF server. Here's the page:

https://iiif.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/iiif/image/c444f7e2-ca30-48ae-87b5-54f93d6ed046/full/full/0/default.jpg

(I got the id for that page from a [GUI page](https://digital.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/inquire/Discover/Search/#/?p=c+0,t+,rsrs+0,rsps+10,fa+,so+ox%3Asort%5Easc,scids+,pid+db2fade4-61ee-4a11-a894-19361c551eed,vi+c444f7e2-ca30-48ae-87b5-54f93d6ed046))

I thought I could get the metadata for that page with the /info.json route:

https://iiif.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/iiif/image/c444f7e2-ca30-48ae-87b5-54f93d6ed046/info.json

But this doesn't include all pages in the book. Does anyone know how one can obtain all pages from a book using the IIIF spec/API? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, googling for `https://iiif.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/iiif/mirador/c444f7e2-ca30-48ae-87b5-54f93d6ed046` today I saw two results: this post and https://iiif.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/iiif/mirador/c444f7e2-ca30-48ae-87b5-54f93d6ed046.

The latter contains all pages in the book, so I suppose the lesson is to search to see if the given IIIF server has a mirador viewer set up, and if so, to ping that...

Also, the manifest route contains all links expressed cleanly: https://iiif.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/iiif/manifest/db2fade4-61ee-4a11-a894-19361c551eed.json